# Mellin transform of powers of gamma function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, soft-question

If $a>0$, the  Cahen-Mellin integral gives
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{\operatorname{Res}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{a-i\infty}^{a+i \infty}\varGamma(z) u^{-z}dz=e^{-u}=\sum\limits_{m=0}^{\infty}\Res_{z=-m}\Gamma(z)u^{-z}
$$
My question is the following: if $k$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$,
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{a-i\infty}^{a+i \infty}\varGamma^k(z) u^{-z}dz=\sum\limits_{m=0}^{\infty}\Res_{z=-m}\Gamma^k(z)u^{-z}=f(u)
$$
Does the series converge for all $u$? What kind of function $f(u)$ (increasing, decreasing) do I have?

Answer (score 1):

For $k\in\mathbb{N}$ one has the inverse Mellin transform
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{a-i\infty}^{a+i \infty}\varGamma^k(z) u^{-z}dz=G_{0,k}^{k,0}\left(u\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 0^{\otimes k} \\
\end{array}
\right.\right),$$
with $G$ the [Meijer-G function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function) and $0^{\otimes k}$ is the string $0,0,0\ldots 0$ of length $k$. For $k=1$ this is the exponential $e^{-u}$ and for $k=2$ this is a Bessel function (modified Bessel function of the second kind),
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{a-i\infty}^{a+i \infty}\varGamma^2(z) u^{-z}dz=2 K_0\left(2 \sqrt{u}\right).$$
I don't know of a more explicit representation of the Meijer-G function for $k\geq 3$. Some plots suggest it is a decaying function of $u>0$ for all $k$.

Comment: Does the integral
$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{a-i\infty}^{a+i \infty}\varGamma^k(z) u^{-z}dz=...
$
exist for all complex value $u$, i.e. Meijer-G function defined for the  complex values? What does   mean  $0^{\otimes k}$? 
For the second integral
$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{a-i\infty}^{a+i \infty}\varGamma^2(z) u^{-z}dz=2K_0(\sqrt u). 
$
What kind of Bessel function is $K_0$? Does the second equation  valid only for real $u$?

Comment: I added the definitions you asked for; I think you need $u>0$ for convergence.

Comment: No, $u$ should be  the complex variable.